# Oracle AQ CLOB JmsTemplate

Tags: oracle, clob

Using java and jmstemplate, I am trying to enqueue a message to an oracle queue with a payload containing a CLOB field.

my question is how do you do such a thing? looking on google there are various suggestions which indicates that I have to:

1. enqueue a message with an empty load
2. retrieve the usr_data from the queue table using the message id created in step 1
3. write the clob to the queue table.

unfortunately not many samples are available and I was wondering if anyone had done this previously and/or has some example code?

Regards,

Yoann.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Oracle 9i Application Developers Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96587.pdf) - Advanced Queueing
See Appendix A - Oracle Advanced Queueing by Example

The last example is called "Enqueuing and Dequeuing Object Type Messages That Contain LOB Attributes Using Java" which might help you out.

The example itself is several pages in size so cant post it here.

You can also check later documents depending on which Oracle you are using to see if they have an updated example but i couldnt find a similar document for 11g.